# Python: Apply function to expanding subset of matrix rows

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

suppose I have the following array:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

I now want to calculate the following sum:

```
np.cos(A[0])+np.cos(A[1])*np.sin(A[0])+np.cos(A[2])*np.sin(A[1])*np.sin(A[0])+np.cos(A[3])*np.sin(A[2])*np.sin(A[1])*np.sin(A[0])
```

What is an efficient way to do this for a general array?

Comment: Your logic is not fully clear due to the `...`, please provide a fixed length example and describe the operation more clearly. Shouldn't the first item be multiplied by `np.sin(d)`?

Comment: can you provide a desired output for an example input? Can you also provide some info about the length of `A`? without this info it wouldn't be possible to choose the most efficient way to compute it.

Answer (score 0):

The logic isn't fully clear, but assuming you want to multiply each values `cos` with the `sin` of the previous value and for the first value with the `sin` of the last value, you can [`roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), then multiply and [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
(np.cos(A)*np.sin(np.roll(A, 1))).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks, but does this also work when A is a matrix or more general tensor? E.g. what if I wanted to apply the same logic to columns of a matrix?

Comment: I don't think this solution matches with the problem. I think each values `cos` has to be multiplied with all previous `sin` values.

Comment: @Algebro1000 I asked you in comment to clarify what you want with a clear example (without `...`), please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Basing on what you've written you'd have the sum of various factors, where each `i-th` factor is the product of the cosine of the `i-th` element and sines of all previous elements. If this is true, you can perform a double `for` cycle in this whay:

```
np.sum([np.cos(A[i]) * np.prod([np.sin(A[j]) for j in range(i)]) for i in range(len(A))])
```

Without additional information is hard to asses if a more efficient way exist.

Assuming you have enough RAM, a loop-free solution is:

```
# define a sines matrix NxN
sin_matrix = np.sin(A)[None, :].repeat(10, axis=0)

# replace the sines whith 1 (neutral for the product) where index >= column
sin_matrix[np.arange(len(A))[:,None]<=np.arange(len(A))[None, :]] = 1
```

and the output is:

```
np.cos(A)*sin_matrix.prod(axis=1)
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to do it entirely without loops if that is possible